# How can I simply integrate the expression $\sin(y^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have

$$\int_0^1\int_{2x}^2\sin\left(y^2\right)\,dy\,dx$$

and I'm not sure how I can integrate the inner integral without it becoming a monster of a equation that would be overly big to carry on with. Supposed to be done with a function calculator.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of integration?

Comment: How exactly does the order swap work here? I gathered that I have to find the domains for x and y and apply them to integrals, but not the details of it

Comment: the solution is a Fresnel-integral

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No, it's perfectly elementary.

Comment: ok, then Show us

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Please see qbert's hint on how to change the order of integration.

Comment: ok i will work after the hint

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner it is completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The bounds of your integral are 
$$
2x\leq y \leq 2\\
0\leq x\leq 1
$$
which is equivalent to saying
$$
0\leq x \leq \frac{y}{2}\\
0\leq y\leq 2
$$

More than a hint:
$$
\int_0^1\int_{2x}^2\sin\left(y^2\right)\,dy\,dx\stackrel{\text{Fubini's}}{=}
\int_0^2\int_{0}^{\frac{y}{2}}\sin\left(y^2\right)\,dx\,dy\\
=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2y\sin\left(y^2\right)\,dy\\
=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^4\sin\left(u\right)\,du\\
=\frac{1}{4}(1-\cos 4)\\
$$

Comment: nice solution! qbert

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the hint, I can see why 
$2x≤y≤2$

$0≤x≤1$

leads to $0≤x≤y/2$,

but is it in $y$'s terms $0≤y≤2$, because you can transform 

$0≤x≤1$ into $0≤2x≤2$ and that can be injected to the first statement in the hint to get the left side, $0$ and the right side of the statement would stay as $2$?

Comment: @Grak in this case, I would really recommend drawing a picture to see the region in question

Answer (score 2):

Be
$$\Theta(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x<0\\
1 & x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$
Then you can rewrite your integral as
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_{2x}^2\sin\left(y^2\right)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx
&= \int_0^1\int_0^2\Theta(y-2x)\sin\left(y^2\right)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_0^2\int_0^1\Theta(y-2x)\sin\left(y^2\right)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_0^2\int_0^1\Theta(y-2x)\,\mathrm dx\,\sin\left(y^2\right)\,\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_0^2\int_0^{y/2}\,\mathrm dx\,\sin\left(y^2\right)\,\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_0^2 \frac{y}{2}\sin\left(y^2\right)\,\mathrm dy\\
\end{align}
The step where $\Theta$ is introduced works because the theta function is $1$ on the original range of the integral and $0$ on the additional range. The removal of the theta function works in an analogous way.

Comment: what is this technique?

Comment: I'm not sure this has a name. It's just using the fact that integrating over $0$ doesn't give a contribution to the integral.